# Eliminating dependence in user class that is created at runtime

Tags: design-patterns, dependency-injection

I have a user class that is created at run-time in my business layer and has methods like AddPrefrence, CreateItem and delete. These methods require accesses to a repository. To eliminate dependency I have used the DI container unity to inject the repository in other parts of the application but here I have become a bit stuck as i have to pass in the user info that is only available at run-time. I think there are ways to pass a run-time parameter in unity but this seems like a bit of a code smell, i have also considered an abstract factory but it seems like a bit overkill as this is the only concrete class it will actually have to create. I have also thought about using a different sort of injection, property injection for example.

Is there a clear answer to this problem and could you please give the advantages and disadvantage of the solution or pattern you suggest. Thank you very much.

Edit: In the end I spit my User class into a User class to hold data and a UserServices class to interact with the repository as i think my User class was violating the single responsibility principle. This also allows me to inject my repository and just pass in the id of the User. It ended up being a relatively easy refactor. I also recommend a read of the link in Steven's  comment below if you are having a similar problem to me as while i did not use a technique in the article it helped answer some of the questions i had.

Comment: The answer can be found in [this article](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99).

Comment: Thanks that was useful. In the end i decided to split this class into a user class that holds hold the data and a user service that interacts with the repository, as I think my user was violating single responsibility.